# Can Shell32 extraction work with a progressbar?

Tags: vb.net, zip, shell32

I'm trying to make my program extract a .zip file, deliver it's content in a folder, while showing progress in a progressbar. If i somewhat cont get the progressbar thing to work, i would also apprieciate if the "Unzipper" could just switch to another form.
Heres the code i currently got for extraction:

```
    Dim sc As New Shell32.Shell()
    'Create directory in which you will unzip your files .
    IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Users\NikolajBanke\Desktop\Test\Unzipped")
    'Declare the folder where the files will be extracted
    Dim output As Shell32.Folder = sc.NameSpace("C:\Users\NikolajBanke\Desktop\Test\Unzipped")
    'Declare your input zip file as folder  .
    Dim input As Shell32.Folder = sc.NameSpace("C:\Users\NikolajBanke\Desktop\Test\peace.zip")
    'Extract the files from the zip file using the CopyHere command .
    output.CopyHere(input.Items, 4)
```

Thank you for any help i would get :)

Comment: Why does it not work? Do you not see the progress bar, or do you get errors?

Comment: It does work, but i have no progress bar. I do not knwo how to get the extraction process displayed in the progressbar. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `output.CopyHere(input.Items, 4)` to `output.CopyHere(input.Items, 16)`
Now you get the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion ZipArchive is way better, cause you can handle the progressbar event, dont forget to include "System.IO.Compression" reference.

```
    Public Async Function Extraer(zipFilePath As String, extractPath As String) As Task
    Dim elzip As ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFilePath)
    Dim lacuenta As Integer = elzip.Entries.Count
    For i = 0 To lacuenta - 1
        Dim entry As ZipArchiveEntry = elzip.Entries(i)
        If entry.Name.Trim = "" Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName))
        Else
            Try
                entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName))
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
        ProgressBar1.Value = (i / (lacuenta - 1)) * 100
    Next
End Function
```